# Limit of integrals on a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a measure space and $f: X \to [0,+\infty]$ and integrable function with positive integral and $a>1$
>
> Prove that $\int_X n\log{(1+\frac{f^a(x)}{n^a})}d\mu(x) \to^{n \to +\infty}0$

Clearly we are interested at $x \in X$ where $f(x)>0$

Let $f(x)>0$. Then it is easy to see that $f_n(x):=n\log{(1+\frac{f^a(x)}{n^a})} \to 0$

The problem is that i did not come up with something to dominate $f_n(x)$ except $f^a$ which does not tell so much for $a>1$

We do not know if $f^a$ is integrable.

Also i believe that this statement may not hold in general but i could not come up with a counterexample.

Can some give me a hint for this problem or giving a counterexample in case the statement is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it were possibly some sort of monotone, but it seems that it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\alpha>1$ there exists a constant $C>0$ such that

$$1+x^{\alpha} \leq e^{Cx} \quad \text{for all $x \geq 0$}.$$

This implies

$$\log(1+x^{\alpha}) \leq Cx, \qquad x \geq 0.$$

Hence,

$$0 \leq n \log \left(1 +\frac{f(x)^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}} \right)\leq Cn \frac{f(x)}{n}=C f(x) \in L^1(\mu).$$

Since

$$n \log \left(1 +\frac{f(x)^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}} \right) \to 0$$

it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that

$$\int_X n \log \left(1 +\frac{f(x)^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}\right) \, d\mu(x) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0.$$

Comment: How do you find that $C$? i know it is true even for $C=1$ for large $x$ since the exponential dominates $x^a$ but here we are interested in $x \in [0,1]$(since $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$)...i know of course that it is true for $C=a=1$

Comment: I believe that $C=a>1$ works

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, it does. You can for instance use the theorem of fundamental calculus. Take $x \in [0,1]$ and set $f(x) := 1+x^{\alpha}$ and $g(x) =\exp(\alpha x)$. Clearly, $f(0)=g(0)$, $f'(x) \leq \alpha$ and $g'(x) \geq \alpha$. Hence, $$f(x)-f(0) = \int_0^x f'(y) \, dy \leq \int_0^x \alpha \, dy \leq \int_0^y g'(y) \, dy = g(x)-g(0)$$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..(i  also upvoted yesterday )